# What are the windows servers that needs to be running on a Search hosted Server SP 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, enterprise-search, topology

I have a server in a farm (App, wfe) where all my search components are running on a single server (App), what are the windows services (in services.msc) needs to be started?

If my search is scaled out like (Crawler on one server and indexer and query ) on other server, what are the services thats needs to be started the respective servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never be interacting with services.msc with regards to SharePoint Search (unless stopping it for patching purposes). If you deploy a particular Search role to a particular server, it will start the necessary services. There are only two Search services; the Host Controller service which monitors the SharePoint Search service.

Comment: Exactly! My patching literally screwed up my search. Initially i see those services only started on my App server, now i see them started on my WFE as well, i hosted search only on APP Server.. should i go head and turn them off?

Comment: I see, yes if you only have the components on the App server, then the Search Host Controller/SharePoint Search services would only need to be started on the App server.